# How do I set the minimum quantity and default quantity to be different?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5, magento2-4-5

I would like to configure my Magento store (Version: Magento 2.4.5) to have a Minimum Quantity of 1 and a Default Quantity of 5 for the products.
Could you please provide me with instructions or guidance on how to make these specific changes?

I have tried:
***Store > Catalog > Inventory > Product Stock Options > Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart***
but this Set both Minimum Quantity and Default Quantity to 1

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is no native way to set a different Minimum Quantity and Default Quantity.

Here is how Magento determines which is the "Default Quantity" :

> \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View::getProductDefaultQty

```php
    public function getProductDefaultQty($product = null)
    {
        if (!$product) {
            $product = $this->getProduct();
        }

        $qty = $this->getMinimalQty($product);
        $config = $product->getPreconfiguredValues();
        $configQty = $config->getQty();
        if ($configQty > $qty) {
            $qty = $configQty;
        }

        return $qty;
    }
```

You can see Magento will either get the Minimal Qty (`$this->getMinimalQty($product)`), or from a "preconfigured value" (`$product->getPreconfiguredValues()`).

This preconfigured value is generaly only defined when you have a *buyRequest* parameter, meaning you are editing a product (from cart, whishlist, ...).

#### Solution

A solution would be to create an "after" plugin on the following method :
`\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::getPreconfiguredValues`.

In this plugin, you can verify if `$preConfiguredValues->getQty()` has been set, and if not, you can define it with your custom Default Quantity.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the product level by editing the product and going under the Advanced Inventory option and un-tik the  Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart and filling in the minimum value.
[image]

Comment: This solution is similar to what OP tried. I think what OP wants is to be able to define a Minimum Qty to 1, but showing a different value by default on the product page : Products page shows a qty of 5, but customer can lower the value down to 1.

Comment: @Cladiuss is right, this is what I want.